# Como inserto un valor default o null en Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo un formulario, son alrededor de 50 campos, pero el punto es que en ocasiones el usuario solo llenará 10 o 20 campos no son los 50 siempre,

entonces tenía el required en mis formularios y lo quite, para que ya no fuera obligatorio completar todos los campos, y en la bd todos los campos están en Null,

pero al llenar 5 campos, no los inserta, no se como hacer para que mínimo si están vacíos me inserte un 0 como default. Los inserta sólo cuando se completan todos los campos.

Un campo del formulario (los demás campos son asi solo cambian los nombres) HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="txtm9a1" id="txtm9a1" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtm9a1'];?>">
```

Inserción por arreglo en PHP:

```
$insertar_de[44]=$_POST['txtm9a1'];
```

Estructura de la tabla, son 50 campos pero todos son iguales a este, claro tiene su llave primaria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución que realice para insertar un campo vacio, fue validar el post

```
 if (empty($_POST['txtm9a1'])) { //Si esta vacio el campo

    $insertar_de[44] = 0; //en mi caso inserta 0, pero puede ser null tambien.

} else if (!empty($_POST['txtm9a1'])) { // Y si esta lleno el campo manda lo que se lleno en la caja de texto

    $insertar_de[44] = $_POST['txtamp1']; //Insertar lo que tiene la caja txt.
```

Comment: Es importante que comentes cómo tomas los datos del formulario para luego insertarlos, por ejemplo, si los envías al servidor mediante Ajax con jQuery. Como posible solución, podrías crear una consulta de inserción dinámica, que se construya según los valores que tengan datos en el formulario: `INSERT INTO (campo1, campo2, campo3...) VALUES (?,?,?)`. Los campos que no estén en el `INSERT` tomarán los valores por defecto que les hayas dado cuando creaste la tabla.

Comment: Falta información deberías mostrar cómo haces la consulta y la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: Actualizo la informacion, lo inserto mediante una funcion que esta detro de un constructor y la estructura de la tabla los datos son int y son null, solo eso

Comment: Puedes configurar desde MySQL valores por defecto a tus columnas, para que en tus sentencias no tengas que incluír forzosamente todas las columnas, si no solo aquellas donde el usuario llenó información.

Comment: Como puedo hacer eso? en la opción predeterminado de Mysql?